# What is the total amount of damage dealt by poison spells?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Like the title says, I wondering what the total amount of damage that can be dealt by each level of poison spell is.

Comment: Related: [What troops can 1 poison spell kill?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/241089/4797)

Comment: I'd be interested to know how much damage is dealt by overlapping poisons at specific times as well, i.e. how much damage does dropping another poison spell 3 seconds into the first one do in total?

Comment: @Alex the way poison spells work, i think after 3 seconds the max damage per second is already reached, so the spell would only last 3 seconds longer, therefore it would do 3X max damage per second more damage. Poison spell damage doesn't stack, but it does increase the ramp up speed to max damage per second

Comment: @Dragonrage The max damage definitely isn't reached after 3 seconds... where did you get that? I'd say it's closer to 10 or so, right?

Comment: @Alex the poison spell ramps up fairly quick, but the unit has to be inside the poison spell as the ramp up is per unit. So if a dragon flies into the poison spell the damage will start ramping up as soon as it enters, but if another troop walks or flies into it, the damage will have to ramp up for that unit as well.

Comment: @Dragonrage Yeah, you are correct. It takes like 5-6 seconds to kill skeleton traps skeletons which have very low HP, so I'm doubting it's ticking at max damage after 3 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Max per second:

1. With a level 1 poison spell 90 damage will be done per second.
2. Level 2 will do 115 per second.
3. Level 3 will do 145
4. and level 4 will do 180.

Although the damage done increases so does other aspects like the speed decrease and there attack rate decrease.

1. At level 1 the speed decrease is 26%
2. At level 2 the speed decrease is 30%
3. At level 3 the speed decrease is 34%
4. And at level 4 the speed decrease is 38%

For the attack decrease these are the level changes

1. The attack rate decrease at level 1 is 35%
2. The attack rate decrease at level 2 is 40%
3. The attack rate decrease at level 3 is 45%
4. And the attack rate decrease at level 4 is 50%

other requirements will change as you upgrade such as cost and research time.

Comment: That is the max damage dealt per second, there is a period of time over which the amount of damage is less than that an increasing. Also, the spell will continue to damage units for a period of time after the spell wears off.

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate the damage as it lessens, but I do see your point.

Comment: I suppose a timing test will have to be done.

Comment: The last update (Mar 21, 2016) also causes idle troops to run out of the poison spell, so it may be even harder to get good measurements.